# Ubuntu: permission denied to FSL Directory

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions, file-handling

In my script i have referred the path  to FSL directory as follows

```
export FSLDIR=/usr/share/fsl/5.0
${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
```

and when i run the script i am incurring following error

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~/Documents/Pipelines-master/PreFreeSurfer$   
./PreFreeSurferPipeline.mine.sh

./PreFreeSurferPipeline.mine.sh: line
170: /usr/share/fsl/5.0/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh: Permission denied
```

How can i possibly change the permissions in the case so that my script can access the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need execute permissions:

```
sudo chmod +X /usr/share/fsl/5.0/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh
```